# Overriding global functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecma

After overriding the Array function, why the behavior of the two objects is different?

```js
function Array(){}

var array1 = ['1','2']
var array2 = new Array();

console.log(array1.length);     // 2
console.log(array2.length);     // undefined
```

Also, `Object()` returns an empty object instance but with a user-defined function, we must use `new` operator, why?

Comment: `new Array()` calls the constructor of the new class you have created. It doesn't have a constructor, so it creates an empty Object, without 'length' property. Hence the `undefined`

Comment: Cause the Array literal does not look up `"Array"` in `window`. It has an internal reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That (`Object()` without `new`) is a shortcut, which you can provide too:

```js
function Stuff(x){
  if(!(this instanceof Stuff)){
    console.log("You forgot 'new'");
    return new Stuff(x);
  }
  this.x=x;
}

var a=Stuff(1);
var b=new Stuff(2);
console.log(a,b);
```

And yes, when you locally override the built-in `Array`, you are stuck with that one. But already existing arrays remain to be original, they do not get fitted retroactively to your own type, and the `[]` syntax is not affected by your override (case of `c`):

```js
var a=[1,2];
var b=new Array(3,4);

(function(){
  function Array(){}
  var c=[1,2];
  var d=new Array(3,4);
  console.log("a:",a);
  console.log("b:",b);
  console.log("c:",c);
  console.log("d:",d);
})()
```

(The function-magic is necessary for `b` to remain unaffected by function hoisting)

Comment: why `[]` syntax is not affected?

Comment: @GauravChaudhary ```[]``` is an *array literal*, an array itself. Practically it does not construct an array, it describes one. It is not very entertaining, but you can read about its interpretation in the standard, https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer

Comment: Thanks, @tevemadar Things are more clear now. It is just the way JavaScript has been designed